# Sending HTTP request with certificate and key as strings in ABAP w/o STRUST config?

Tags: rest, http, certificate, abap

I want to use a REST API in ABAP, which requires a certificate and key, **without configuration in STRUST**.

In ABAP, I would have to create an instance of HTTP client and then send an HTTP request. I want to add the certificate and key as strings to that HTTP request.

Could anyone please provide an example how the code should look like? Do I have to add the strings to the request header or body? What are the field names I have to use?

Thanks!

In Postman, I added the certificate and key in settings with a corresponding URL. Then, sent a POST request to that URL and it worked. However, I don't know what are the HTTP request fields names Postman uses.

Comment: Explain in details what you did in Postman, what you tried in ABAP, what you searched  and what was the ABAP result. Only after that I think your question can be relevant for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked in the past.
Postman can use the client cert for the TLS handshake.
The equivalent is ABAP is to register the PSE version of certificate in STRUST. And unlike Postman which can accept CRT and private key , ABAP strust wants the PSE/PFX equivalent for import to STRUST.  I really dont see a way around STRUST, as the X509 cert is used at TLS level.  You should probably discuss what you are trying with SYS admins for the SAP system.

Comment: Agree with phil, impossible without STRUST